# background html css

Tags: html, css

Всем привет. Я добавил bg к header. И по макету нужно, чтобы нижняя часть телефона уходила за границы header. Я это сделал, но bg не просто кончается, а начинается как бы новый) Я делал no-repeat и bg просто пропадает, подскажите, что делать? Заранее спасибо[image]

Comment: я попробую догадаться - вы сдвигаете iphone наружными отступами ?

Comment: пробовал и padding и margin

Comment: добавьте код сюда - гадать обычно ходят в [сюда](https://otvet.mail.ru/chiromancy/)

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте background-size:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: тогда изображение просто увеличивается, а мне надо чтобы оставался белый фон

Comment: Тогда попробуйте это "background-size: contain;"

Comment: вы читали хоть что делает background-size: contain;? Масштабирует изображение с сохранением пропорций таким образом, чтобы картинка целиком поместилась внутрь блока.

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  display: table;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.left-col {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.right-col {
  float: right;
  width:50%;
}

.img {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="left-col">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam impedit similique id dignissimos nobis sed iste temporibus veniam facere, ipsa ea harum reprehenderit maxime sapiente! Repellendus doloribus itaque consectetur ducimus?
  </div>
  <div class="right-col">
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```